# Use of STATE_CLEANUP_DELAY_MS_CONFIG

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

in StreamsConfig there is a parameter STATE_CLEANUP_DELAY_MS_CONFIG which says "The amount of time in milliseconds to wait before deleting state when a partition has migrated. Only state directories that have not been modified for at least `state.cleanup.delay.ms` will be removed";

We have multiple state directories due to rebalancing, deployments, etc in file system

1. This will clean those directories? I tried this parameter, restarted the consumer but old state directories are still there

Answer (score 1):

Note that Kafka Streams will only delete *task directories* that are nested inside the `state.dir`, and only for the current application. Thus, if you have multiple *state directories* because you changed the `application.id` you would need to delete old state directories manually.

Comment: As per kafka logs current active tasks: [1_3, 2_2, 0_5, 1_4, 2_3, 0_6, 1_5] and then I receive messages that Deleting obsolete state directory 0_5 for task 0_5 as 60555ms has elapsed (cleanup delay is 60000ms) which it fails due to checkpoint tem  not found. Also i could not find task directory 0_5 in state directory. Why it tries to delete task directory which is active ? and why no task directory for task 0_5 in state directory

Comment: Also when one machine(consumer) goes down tasks are distributed in other nodes as per logs. But I could not find new task directories. For example, node 1 says  [0_0, 0_1, 1_0, 0_2, 1_1, 2_0, 0_3, 1_3, 0_5, 1_4] active tasks after partition assignment, but in this machine there is no directories nested with name 0_ in state directory.

Comment: There is a know bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5998 for the checkpoint not found issue. Maybe you hit it. For the second part, I am not sure atm. Sounds suspicious, but hard to tell why the task directories are not created...

Comment: 1110471ms has elapsed (cleanup delay is 600000ms)
Cleanup is happening way after configured delay. Is this a normal behaviour? Also what is the max delay that can happen?

Comment: if we have StickyAssignor in place, will cleanup still take place? As in lets suppose if after 5 hours, our consumer is up again, then state directory movement will take place?

Comment: For cleanup, there is a background thread that checks if some task directory is expired using the cleanup interval as sleeping time in between checks. Hence, if something expires shortly after the check, it make sense that the elapse time can be up to 2x cleanup interval.

Comment: `f we have StickyAssignor in place, will cleanup still take place?` -- cleanup is independent of the assignment if you wish. As long as a task is active, no cleanup will happen for this tasks. Only if a task is migrated away, the corresponding directory is cleaned up after the cleanup timeout expires.

Comment: Does the clean up thread look into standby tasks as well ? It appears that in some cases the cleanup and restore happening in cycles.

Comment: The cleanup thread does not know anything about active/standby tasks. However, if an active or standby is assigned to an instance, it would hold a `.lock` on its task directory and thus the cleanup thread should not delete the task directory.

Comment: Hello, @MatthiasJ.Sax, how we can respect the Kafka recommandation to have an unique application.id per version and start from a clean situation on each version, and in same time make sure old store are deleted?